# Poor image rendering with Google Docs PDF viewer

Tags: pdf, google-docs, viewer

I used Word 2007 to create a PDF file with an 1526px * 900px image filling a whole page. This is not the first time it's happened, but Google Docs PDF viewer absolutely mangles the colour rendering making it unusable.

I've taken screenshots at the same zoom level in Google Docs viewer and Foxit Reader.

Here's an image for comparison:

[image]

It's awful!  I've tried messing about with some things, but can't find anything that can correct this issue.

Comment: I've still been unable to find an image based PDF that will display properly: https://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://www.belokovsky.com/Vadim-Belokovsky-Portfolio.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let it be recorded here, 16 months after the present original posting by Turkeyphant and a similar posting [1] on the Docs+Drive product forum, that the problem appears to have been fixed within about the past week. Since that time, when a pdf (or Word) file is opened that resides on the Docs+Drive cloud, the file is rendered with what appears to be proper 24-bit color. The treatment whereby the color was reduced to 5 bits, which could encode 32 colors or 32 shades of gray or 16 of each, depending on the image, has been abandoned.

To the best of my knowledge the Docs+Drive staff have not announced this change, either on their Blog or on their product forum. I noticed the change a few days ago and noted it on the conversation [1].

[1] (2013-05-21) Problem in pdf-viewer with color images
https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/_bdfiYgjF2s/5PDMdp9MhFQJ

Answer (score 21):

In Chrome you can select "Print" and then "Save as PDF". The image quality in the saved PDF file will go up significantly, compared to the one from "Download as PDF". Google seems to be optimizing images to preserve bandwidth.

Comment: This is the correct solution. Thanks, you saved me a lot of trouble. However, this only works 50% of the time. Docs seems to randomly choose between low-res and high-res PDF generation (which is probably a race condition). So if anyone else can't get this to work, try it a few times, checking the output PDF file each time. (You can probably tell even from the print preview whether it's generating a blurry version or a high-res version.)

Answer (score 2):

It might have something to do with compression of the image in the PDF.

I mean, PDF supports JPEG2000-encoded images (`JPXDecode` Filter) and PDF Reference states that:

> From a single JPEG2000 data stream, **multiple versions** of an image may
>   be decoded. These different versions form progressions along four
>   **degrees of freedom: sampling resolution, color depth**, band, and
>   location. For example, with a resolution progression, a thumbnail
>   version of the image may be decoded from the data, followed by a
>   sequence of other versions of the image, each with approximately four
>   times as many samples (twice the width times twice the height) as the
>   previous one. **The last version is the full-resolution image.**

Google Docs viewer might be displaying  only first version of the image (with lower resolution or lower color depth) thus producing "awful" output.

Comment: Bob - I'm sure it's to do with compression, I'm not not sure where. I'm not 100% convinced that its another compression version within the PDF though - I think it's to do with the compression Google uses to render PDFs for web (mainly converting to an image and overlaying text on top).

Comment: I tried saving the images as PNGs, GIFs, and JPGs with pretty much every combination of compression settings and they always came out as in the top image when seen in the viewer.

HOWEVER, I managed to produce similar results by using Photoshop to save the file as a 32-colour GIF with NO DITHERING.

[See here](http://i.imgur.com/LS49R0b.png)  (top image is screengrab from Google viewer, bottom is 32 colour GIF).

So it seems Google is doing some heavy colour compression and not dithering at all. But I can't for the life of me work out why some images are okay and some as bad as this. Wah!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the attached pair of images will help towards clarifying what is happening with color in images that are rendered through the Google Docs pdf viewer. I inserted the Wikipedia image RGB_Color_Solid_Cube (1024*1024 pixels) into an otherwise empty Google Docs text document, converted it to pdf, and viewed the resulting pdf files two ways: once through the Google Docs+Drive pdf viewer and once through the regular pdf viewer of the Chrome or Firefox browser. Then I made screenshots. Here is the [RGB Color Cube via the Docs PDF Viewer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lu1smesxlpbsuck/RGB_Color_Solid_Cube-DocsPDFViewer.png) and here is the [RGB Color Cube via a regular browser PDF Viewer](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lo569hhftdgre1x/RGB_Color_Solid_Cube-RegularPDFViewer.png).

The color resolution in the Docs PDF Viewer version is really awful; it looks like 64 colors at most. Maybe someone else is able to recognize this kind of rendering and identify the problem better.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to compression and it's something that you can't change in the default view of Google Docs Viewer. The simple solution is to upload the PDF and just serve it from the site in an iFrame.  Here is an example:

[Problem Embedding Google Docs PDF Solution](http://brainchamber.com/2013/07/11/problems-embedding-pdf-files-in-web-pages/)

Mike